# Best practices with SVN for files that always "change" with no change

Tags: svn, visualsvn, pre-commit

We have a project that references files in a Common-directory. Whenever that project is opened or compiled, these files are copied. Because the timestamp changes, Subversion sees that as changes. I only want to commit new changes of the general Common-directory, or actual changes in the project. Not the auto-copies that the compiler performs for me.

How do I keep the directory and the files in SVN, but prevent these non-changes to be seen as changes? Is there some "best practice" or "preferred" way of dealing with such situations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, you don't want to put compiler-generated anything into your repository.  Use [svn:ignore](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/662.cfm) to ignore these things.

Comment: Ah, that reminds me of my CVS days. Figured something like that should exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would think a simple svn:ignore on the common directory would do. The files that don't really change should be checked in to a separate project. You would have to tell your developers that  they will have to checkout the two project but only check in the project with the files that really change.

Comment: Actually, I should place the svn:ignore in the bin directory, the Common directory should be monitored. The bin only contains pointers to files in the Common directory, which get copied there on opening or running the project. Thanks for the tip on separating the projects (but that's that part that's apparently already done so ;-)